# how to looping to display markers in google maps v3 from traceroute output

Tags: php, javascript, loops, google-maps-api-3, markers

I'm newbie in php mysql and google maps v3. I have a problems in google maps v3. I made traceroute web based and map the traceroute's result in the google maps v3 for my final project of my college education. I have try so many tutorials but it didn't work. I also have tried the tutorials in this forum but nothing worked. So my problem is I cannot display multiple markers that I got the location data from database. maybe because I'm newbie and do not know how to do. I also confuse with the looping to show the markers. So here is the php code:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ (E_NOTICE));
ini_set('max_execution_time', 360);
$enable_log_user = FALSE;

global $ip, $host_name,  $host_ip, $output, $integer;

$host  = @$_POST['host']; 
$trace = @$_POST['trace'];
$self  = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];

include("phpsqlajax_dbinfo.php");
$connection = mysql_connect ('127.0.0.1', $username, $password);
if (!$connection) {  die('Not connected : ' . mysql_error());} 

$db_selected = mysql_select_db($database, $connection);
if (!$db_selected) {
  die ('Can\'t use db : ' . mysql_error());
} 

function get_ip()
{
    if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP']))   //check ip from share internet
    {
      $ip=$_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
    }
    elseif (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']))   //to check ip is pass from proxy
    {
      $ip=$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
    }
    else
    {
      $ip=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    }
    return $ip;
}

$ip = get_ip(); 

?>
<!DOCTYPE html >
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
    <title>PHP/MySQL & Google Maps Example</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[

    </script>
  </head>
<body onload="initialize()">
<form name="tools" action="<?php $self ?>" method="post">
    <p><font size="2">Your IP is <?php $ip ?> </font></p>
    <input type="text" name="host" value=""></input>
    <input type="submit" name="trace" value="Traceroute!"></input>
    </form>
    <?php
    if ($_POST['submit']) 
{
    if (($host == 'Enter Host or IP') || ($host == "")) {
        echo '<br><br>You must enter a valid Host or IP address.';
        exit; } 

    if(eregi("^[a-z]",  $host))
    {
        $host_name = $host;
        $host_ip = gethostbyname($host);
    }
    else
    {
        $host_name = gethostbyaddr($host);
        $host_ip = $host;
    } 
}


    $host= preg_replace ("[-a-z0-9!#$%&\'*+/=?^_`{|}~]","",$host);
    $command = "tracert $host";
    $fp = shell_exec("$command 2>&1");
    $output .= (htmlentities(trim($fp)));
    echo "<pre>$output</pre>";
    echo '<br/>';

    $array = array($output);
    $space_separated = implode(" ", $array);

    function explodeRows($data) {
      $rowsArr = explode("\n", $data);
      return $rowsArr;
    }
    function explodeTabs($singleLine) {
      $parsed = preg_split('/ +/', $singleLine);
      return $parsed;
    }
    $data     = $space_separated;
    $rowsArr  = explodeRows($data);

    for($a=3;$a<count($rowsArr)-2;$a++) 
    {
        $lineDetails[$a] = explodeTabs($rowsArr[$a]);

        if (empty($lineDetails[$a][9]))
        {
            $ipList[] = $lineDetails[$a][8];
        }
        else
        {
            $ipList[] = substr($lineDetails[$a][9], 1, -1);
        }
    }

    for ($b=0; $b<count($ipList); $b++)
    {
        if ($ipList[$b] != "")
        {
            $arrLine[]=$ipList[$b];
        }
    }

function ip_address_to_number($IPaddress)
{
    if ($IPaddress == "") {
        return 0;
    } else {
        $ips = explode (".", "$IPaddress");
        return ($ips[3] + $ips[2] * 256 + $ips[1] * 256 * 256 + $ips[0] * 256 * 256 * 256);
    }
}
for($c=0; $c<count($arrLine); $c++) {
$integer[] = ip_address_to_number($arrLine[$c]);
}

    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var pinImage = new google.maps.MarkerImage ("http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_xpin_letter_withshadow&chld=pin_star|%E2%80%A2|CC3300|000000|FF9900",
        new google.maps.Size (70, 83),
        new google.maps.Point (0,0),
        new google.maps.Point (10,34));
    var pinShadow = new google.maps.MarkerImage ("http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_shadow",
        new google.maps.Size (89, 85),
        new google.maps.Point (0, 0),
        new google.maps.point (12, 35));
        var map;
    function initialize() {
    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(41.258531,-96.012599);
    var myOptions = {
    zoom: 2,
    center: myLatlng,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
    <?php
    $posisi = array();
    foreach ($integer as $lokasi) {
    $query = "SELECT cl.locId, cl.country as country, cl.region as region, cl.city as city, cl.postalCode as postalCode, cl.latitude as latitude, cl.longitude as longitude, cl.metroCode as metroCode, cl.areaCode as areaCode
    FROM (SELECT locId as idcihuy FROM cityblocks WHERE $lokasi BETWEEN startIpNum AND endIpNum) cb, citylocation cl WHERE cb.idcihuy = cl.locId";
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    while ($location = @mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $posisi[]= 'new google.maps.LatLng(' . $location['latitude'] . ', ' . $location['longitude'] . ')';
    }
    }
    ?>
    <!-- var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow; -->
     var point = [<?php echo implode(',', $posisi) ?>];
     var icon = pinImage;
     var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: point,
        icon: pinImage,
        shadow: pinShadow
        });
             marker.setMap(map);
        }
    </script>
<div id="map_canvas" style="width: 900px; height: 500px"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

And this is the html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html >

  <head>

    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />

    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>

    <title>PHP/MySQL & Google Maps Example</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

    //<![CDATA[



    </script>

  </head>

<body onload="initialize()">

<form name="tools" action="" method="post">

    <p><font size="2">Your IP is  </font></p>

    <input type="text" name="host" value=""></input>

    <input type="submit" name="trace" value="Traceroute!"></input>

    </form>

    <pre>Tracing route to youtube-ui.l.google.com [173.194.38.129]
over a maximum of 30 hops:

  1   204 ms   238 ms   233 ms  192.168.1.1 
  2   992 ms   241 ms   200 ms  192.168.1.11 
  3   852 ms   239 ms   502 ms  192.168.4.36 
  4  1079 ms   257 ms   281 ms  192.168.4.36 
  5   856 ms   321 ms   306 ms  192.168.1.11 
  6     *        *        *     Request timed out.
  7  1073 ms   239 ms   198 ms  205.128.240.180.telin.sg [180.240.128.205] 
  8   216 ms   292 ms   281 ms  109.190.240.180.telin.sg [180.240.190.109] 
  9   239 ms   239 ms   299 ms  72.14.215.170 
 10  1838 ms   539 ms   508 ms  209.85.243.158 
 11   467 ms   998 ms  1098 ms  72.14.233.79 
 12  1601 ms   239 ms     *     sin04s01-in-f1.1e100.net [173.194.38.129] 
 13   790 ms   356 ms   179 ms  sin04s01-in-f1.1e100.net [173.194.38.129] 

Trace complete.</pre><br/>  <script type="text/javascript">

        var pinImage = new google.maps.MarkerImage ("http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_xpin_letter_withshadow&chld=pin_star|%E2%80%A2|CC3300|000000|FF9900",

        new google.maps.Size (70, 83),

        new google.maps.Point (0,0),

        new google.maps.Point (10,34));

    var pinShadow = new google.maps.MarkerImage ("http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_shadow",

        new google.maps.Size (89, 85),

        new google.maps.Point (0, 0),

        new google.maps.point (12, 35));

        var map;

    function initialize() {

    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(41.258531,-96.012599);

    var myOptions = {

    zoom: 2,

    center: myLatlng,

    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP

    }

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

        <!-- var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow; -->

     var point = [new google.maps.LatLng(1.3667, 103.8000),new google.maps.LatLng(1.3667, 103.8000),new google.maps.LatLng(37.4192, -122.0574),new google.maps.LatLng(37.4192, -122.0574),new google.maps.LatLng(37.4192, -122.0574),new google.maps.LatLng(37.4192, -122.0574)];

     var icon = pinImage;

     var marker = new google.maps.Marker({

        map: map,

        position: point,

        icon: pinImage,

        shadow: pinShadow

        });

        marker.setMap(map);

        }

    </script>

<div id="map_canvas" style="width: 900px; height: 500px"></div>

</body>

</html>
```

Well, I'm really sorry if you guys read my code. It looks mess. Because I don't know how to display the code well. The most important thing I want to be helped is in the maps. For how to show all the markers. Especially the looping. The google maps doesn't show the markers. It only display the maps. So for all the masters who read this question. I just need your help as soon as possible. I'm really sorry if my English was bad and my mistake to you guys.

Comment: Posting a Short, Self Contained, Correct Example (http://sscce.org/)  would definitely increase your chances of an answer. Not many brave souls would go through all that code just to find out what's wrong and/or how to fix it.

Comment: sorry, @Alex, i can't get it clearly. just explain me what do you mean. i'm sorry if i have bad english. thanks.

Comment: Thanks for edited my spelling for @Alex. I would be careful to what I'll write. It's because I still learning speak English.

Comment: Spelling is not that important, the SSCCE is more important. Glad you found that answer. Carry on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you're not giving your markers any position:

```
 var point = [];
 var icon = pinImage;

 var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    position: point,
    icon: pinImage,
    shadow: pinShadow
    });
```

So all you've done is create the position as an empty array.  You need to create a LatLng() there for the position instead.

---

So now you've got an array of points:

```
 var point = [new google.maps.LatLng(1.3667, 103.8000),new google.maps.LatLng(1.3667, 103.8000),new google.maps.LatLng(37.4192, -122.0574),new google.maps.LatLng(37.4192, -122.0574),new google.maps.LatLng(37.4192, -122.0574),new google.maps.LatLng(37.4192, -122.0574)];

 var icon = pinImage;

 var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    position: point,
    icon: pinImage,
    shadow: pinShadow
    });

    marker.setMap(map);
```

What you need to do is loop over the array, creating a marker for each:

```
var point = [new google.maps.LatLng(1.3667, 103.8000),new google.maps.LatLng(1.3667, 103.8000),new google.maps.LatLng(37.4192, -122.0574),new google.maps.LatLng(37.4192, -122.0574),new google.maps.LatLng(37.4192, -122.0574),new google.maps.LatLng(37.4192, -122.0574)];

var icon = pinImage;

for (var i = 0; i < point.length; i++) {
     var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: point[i],
        icon: pinImage,
        shadow: pinShadow
        });
}
```

Also the setMap line is redundant, because when you say map:map, that is all you need to do.

Comment: i'm sorry mr. duncan, i have editted my code in my question. so the point is not an empty array. so for my new edit code, is there any something wrong with the code to display markers?? thanks in advance. sorry for not being clear.

Comment: so that code still doesnt display the markers. would you mind to help me mr.duncan?? i don't know how to fix it :(

Comment: mr.duncan, it really works !!! omg, i really say big thanks for you. your help really means to me. i cannot give you anything. but i just can pray to God, that may God always bless you and make you more success with what you've done to other in this forum. i'm indonesian newbie and i really really appreciated of what you did to me. thank you so much :)

Comment: yes of course mr.duncan. but i don't know how to do. bacause i'm newbie in this forum. can you explain to me how to do?

Comment: click on the check box to the left of my answer.  See: http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask